# Unity Error CS0126

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sure it's something stupid simple, but I can't get it figured out. The following code:

```
public GameObject AISelectCannon() {
    Debug.Log("AISelectCannon called");
    GameObject desiredCannon = AIController.selectCannon(0);
    if (desiredCannon.tag.Contains("Cannon")) return;
    m_SelectedCannon = desiredCannon;
    aiSelectionPending = true;
    return m_SelectedCannon;
}
```

is throwing the following error:

```
Scripts/CubeContainer.cs(61,59): error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to `UnityEngine.GameObject' is required for the return statement
```

(GameObject desiredCannon.... is line 61)

Other relevant information from AIController:

```
public static GameObject selectCannon(int side) {
```

So yeah, any ideas?

Comment: i think its your first return statement after the if, it isnt returning a GameObject

Comment: Changed to return null. Fixed. >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first return statement isnt returning anything, it just says return

```
if (desiredCannon.tag.Contains("Cannon")) return // return something
```